# increment multiple rows in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a bit complex query that I need help with:

`Logic`

1. Table `subscriptions` have rows with `user_id` (each user can have many rows)
2. Table `products` require `tokens` (example 2 tokens is required for product A)
3. Now this tokens has to be calculated based on user subscription amount. Let say user has 2 rows in subscriptions table, one with `1` token and other one with `5` tokens (user have 6 tokens in total) and he need to use `2` of them only.
4. What I'm trying to do here is to update subscriptions table for this user and mark his rows `used_tokens` column by incrementing them.

> You might be confused a bit now! here is screenshots to make it
> visually understandable for you.

`products table`

[image: one]

`subscriptions table`

[image: two]

## Issue

Issue is I cannot make it happen to update `used_tokens` columns in this two rows in `subscriptions` table.

**Here is what it should look like at the end**

[image: three]

## Code

This is what I have so far (getting right product, getting user subscriptions) and I need to update those subscriptions:

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($request->input('product_id')); // Get product
$required_tokens = $product->required_tokens; // Get product require tokens (i.e. 2)
$subscriptions = Subscription::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('isPaid', true)->where('used_tokens', '<', 'tokens')->get(); // Get user subscription rows
```

**How can I update (increment) `used_tokens` in those rows?**

Comment: Instead of spreading the token cost (2) across both subscription rows, would it not be easier to decrement one row until it's depleted then move ont othe next? Or is there a reason they _should_ be spread equally? This raises the question of how to handle it when the cost is 3 for example.

Comment: ``$subscriptions = Subscription::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('isPaid', true)->where('used_tokens', '<', 'tokens')->update(['used_tokens' => DB::raw('used_tokens + 1')]);`` ??

Comment: @OMiShah where in this query makes sure that incremented number `used_tokens` does not goes above `tokens` number and it switch to next row when first row `used_tokens` and `tokens` are equal?

Comment: @mafortis, yes it does.

Comment: @OMiShah didn't you also forget to use `$required_tokens`? where should it know how many tokens it suppose to increment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like that?

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($request->input('product_id'));
$required_tokens = $product->required_tokens;
$subscriptions = Subscription::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('isPaid', true)->where('used_tokens', '<', 'tokens')->get();

$remaining_tokens = $required_tokens;

foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
  if ($remaining_tokens > 0) {
    $row = DB::table('subscriptions')
       ->where('id', $subscription->id)
       ->first();

    if(!empty($row)) {
      $available_tokens = $row->tokens - $row->used_tokens;

      if ($available_tokens > 0) {
        $tokens_to_be_used = ($remaining_tokens >= $available_tokens) ? $available_tokens : $remaining_tokens;

        $final_used_tokens = $row->used_tokens + $tokens_to_be_used;

        DB::table('subscriptions')
           ->where('id', $subscription->id)
           ->update([
               'used_tokens' => final_used_tokens,
           ]);

        $remaining_tokens = $remaining_tokens - $available_tokens;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Final (cleaned up) code

```php
$subscriptions = Subscription::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('isPaid', true)->get();

foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
    if($subscription->used_tokens < $subscription->tokens){
        if ($required_tokens > 0) {
            $available_tokens = $subscription->tokens - $subscription->used_tokens;
            $tokens_to_be_used = ($required_tokens >= $available_tokens) ? $available_tokens : $required_tokens;
            $final_used_tokens = $subscription->used_tokens + $tokens_to_be_used;
            DB::table('subscriptions')
            ->where('id', $subscription->id)
            ->update([
                'used_tokens' => $final_used_tokens,
            ]);
            $required_tokens = $required_tokens - $available_tokens;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where in this query makes sure that incremented number `used_tokens` does not goes above `tokens` number and it switch to next row when first row `used_tokens` and `tokens` are equal?

Comment: Your 3rd command guarantees that used_tokens is smaller than tokens: `$subscriptions = Subscription::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('isPaid', true)->where('used_tokens', '<', 'tokens')->get();`

So that, each subscription record has a room for incrementing. 0 becomes 1 for first row (1 token), 0 becomes 1 for second row (5 tokens). Right?

Comment: yes but didn't you also forget to use `$required_tokens`? where should it know how many tokens it suppose to increment?

Comment: I got you. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it did work (hence accepted answer) but there was issue in comparing `used_tokens` and `tokens` in model query, as well as there was some unnecessary parts in your code. So I've updated your answer with final cleaned up code.

Comment: You did what I was expecting. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can update multiple models at once in laravel using laravel eloquent relationships

```php
#App\Models\User.php
class User extends Authennticable {
    public function subscriptions ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class);
    }
}
```

After setting this relationship, you can update the user's subscriptions using the code below:

```php
$user = User::find($id);

$user->subscriptions()->where(isPaid, true)->upadte(['used_tokens' => 'new_value']);
```